# Trouble with CultureInfo for Norway

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently dealing with globalization in my app.  Part of it is working with CultureInfo and RegionInfo.  There is one issue that really puzzles me.  Maybe someone can shade some light on this:

```
var ci1 = new CultureInfo("de");      // Correct, gives a neutral CultureInfo
var ci2 = new CultureInfo("de-CH");   // Correct, gives a specific CultureInfo
var ci3 = new CultureInfo("fr-CH");   // Correct, gives a specific CultureInfo
var ci4 = new CultureInfo("no");      // Correct, gives a neutral CultureInfo
var ci5 = new CultureInfo("nb-NO");   // Correct, gives a specific  CultureInfo
var ci6 = new CultureInfo("nn-NO");   // Correct, gives a specific  CultureInfo
var ci7 = new CultureInfo("ch");      // Failure!  Can't create a neutral Swiss culture.
```

The point here is, that Norway and Swizerland are both multilingual countries, but in contrast to Norway I am not able to create a neutral Swiss CultureInfo.

Is that because of historical reasons or is this simply a bug in Microsofts implementation?

EDIT:
It seems that this is some kind of 'political' issue, not a technical.  So I would like to rephrase my question:  Any good ideas how to deal with this issue technically?  Simply ignore "***CultureInfo("no")***"?  Interestingly enough "***CultureInfo("no")***" delivers a parent "***CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName***" of 'nb'.

So, for me it is quite confusing.  Any good ideas?

Comment: Just like Canada. No neutral culture, just two specific ones. And that's about as political as it gets here.

Comment: Culture includes objects such as DateTimeFormatInfo, NumberFormatInfo, CompareInfo, and TextInfo that are specific to the culture.  Maybe these are shared between the norweigan languages.  (Maybe MS just weren't aware there were 2 (or 4) norwegian languages when they first branched outside the US  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A neutral culture is a culture that is associated with a *language* but not with a country/region.  See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx

You are trying to create a language culture with ch, but there is no swiss language.  You use de-CH for german (language) - switzerland (country).  Similarly, you use it-CH or fr-CH for italian and french (languages) in switzerland.

And, as MPelletier points out, there is no canadian language, but in the canadian region, they speak fr(ench) or en(glish).

Comment: I am totally with you, and that was also my understanding. But, that does not explain the Norwegian exception. Following your explanation, it should also not possible to create a neutral Norwegian CultureInfo:_**'nb'** - language_, _**'NO'** - country_; _**'nn'** - language_, _**'NO'** - country_.  So why the hack is there a _**'no'**_ neutral culture?

Comment: The way I understand it is it's a neutral "Norwegian language" culture, not a neutral "Norway" culture.

Comment: @MPelletier The two Norwegian languages are quite different as far as I know.  Canada and Swizerland are basically in the same situation.

Comment: Because there is a norwegian language, there is a neutral 'no'.  I guess this would refer to spoken norwegian or whatever is the default written language.  If there is a need to distinguish between the written languages, then the 'nb' or 'nn' languages are used in the 'NO' country.

Comment: @mcalex Does that mean that "norsk, nynorsk (Noreg)" and "norsk, bokmål (Norge)" are just two ways of writing the Norwegian language and there is indeed just one spoken language???

Comment: from wikipedia:  "As established by law and governmental policy, there are two official forms of *written* Norwegian" which I took as suggesting this.  Further on, however, it says everybody speaks their own dialect.  It actually looks like they speak bokmål and østnorsk, not nynorsk. Yeah, there's not a lot of consistency, but then again there usually isn't with languages.  They officially wrote in danish for 300-odd years.  Also, why isn't there a default chinese (language)? +1 on your q.

Comment: Chinese will be different, the pronunciation between dialects is different, but the writing is mostly the same.

Comment: Exactly why there *should* be a default chinese (language)

Comment: Ah! According to Wikipedia, [Bokmål](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokm%C3%A5l) "is used by 85–90% of the population in Norway." That might be why it defaults to this.

Comment: lol, and "the majority *speak* dialects that resemble Nynorsk more closely than Bokmål".  Oh, those crazy Norwegians.

Comment: @mcalex Written Canadian-French is closer to French and than spoken Canadian-French. The French have different date formats and an *AZERTY* keyboard, whereas French-Canadians have a "French-Canadian" keyboard (and a few variations thereof) which is essentially *QUERTY* with extra keys. If's a different *physical* keyboard, even before the letters are painted on. Welcome to the crazy world of cultures and globalization! :)

Comment: uh-huh.  Look at the culture neutral en.  You'd think it would default to english-England (unless you're from one particular country :), but that's globali*s*ation for you

Comment: @Andreas ISO 639 is not in agreement with norwegian authorities.  ISO 639 classifies bokmål and nynorsk as seperate languages under the macro language norwegian.  Norwegian authorities and the language counsels for bokmål and nynorsk classifies bokmål and nynorsk as written norms for the Norwegian language.

Comment: Old discussion, but just to clear this up, from someone that is Norwegian (excluding minority languages here; even Sami, for simplicity): Norway has 2 majority written languages: Nynorsk and Bokmål. Norway has 1 majority spoken language: Norwegian. This is neither Nynorsk nor Bokmål. Our written and spoken languages are distinct, but closely resembled. The spoken Norwegian language is not a language with a defined pronunciation; it consists of all our dialects. We speak Norwegian, and write either NN or NB (Norwegian). NN and NB are very similar. If you can read one, you can read both.

Answer (score 6):

`"no"` has different behavior from `"ch"`, because `"no"` is a language, norwegian, while "ch" does not refer to any language.

While it's correct that Norway is a multilingual country the official languages in Norway are; Norwegian, Sami and Kven.  With Sami and Kven recognised as minority languages.  Neither `"nb"` or `"nn"` refers to languages that have offical recognizion in Norway, because neither bokmål or nynorsk are languages.

The confusion stems from two facts.  Norwegian, unlike most languages, has two offical written norms, Bokmål and Nynorsk.  In ISO 639 Norwegian is considered a macro language for the two norms and ISO 639 assigns a separate language code to the two written norms, ie. "nb" and "nn".  And the language code for Norwegian "no" coincides with the country code for Norway "NO".

Answer (score 3):

According to ISO language standard there is 
nno nn Norwegian Nynorsk; 
nob nb Bokmål, Norwegian; 
nor no Norwegian

From Wikipedia "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_language"
Nynorsk and Bokmål provide standards for how to write Norwegian, but not for how to speak the language. There is no officially sanctioned standard of spoken Norwegian, and most Norwegians speak their own dialects in all circumstances. Thus, unlike in many other countries, the use of any Norwegian dialect, whether it coincides with the written norms or not, is accepted as correct spoken Norwegian.

no is spoken Norwegian
nn and nb are written forms

on a website if you see no-no you can assume it is nb-no.